# Autofit the size of d3js graph in a simple html page

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

This question is originated as per the suggestion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003988/fit-the-d3js-graph-in-a-simple-html-page). As per the suggested edits to fix the issue of first node being cut off, the code looks like follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node circle {
  fill: #999;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.node--internal circle {
  fill: #555;
}

.node--internal text {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-opacity: 0.4;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="960" height="2000"></svg>
<script src="d3.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(60,0)");

var tree = d3.cluster()
    .size([height, width - 160]);

var stratify = d3.stratify()
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.id.substring(0, d.id.lastIndexOf(".")); });

d3.csv("test.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var root = stratify(data)
      .sort(function(a, b) { return (a.height - b.height) || a.id.localeCompare(b.id); });

  tree(root);

  var link = g.selectAll(".link")
      .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
            + "C" + (d.parent.y + 100) + "," + d.x
            + " " + (d.parent.y + 100) + "," + d.parent.x
            + " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
      });

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", 3)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.id.substring(d.id.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the end nodes are cut off, and it looks as follows:
[image]

How to scale it? Sorry for my ignorance with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can regulate the width of the tree to draw into smaller space:

So this code

```
var tree = d3.cluster()
    .size([height, width - 160]);
```

make it this:

```
var tree = d3.cluster()
    .size([height, width - 360]);//reducing the width of the tree by 200
```

This should give more space for the labels.

working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xiy4xbNSl7KGH6NDc8o7?p=preview)